# Interceptor on super method in CDI 1.0/JEE6

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, interceptor

In the following case,

```
public class Base {

    @Transactional
    public void doSave() {
       // ...
    }

 }

 public class Inherited extends Base {

     public void someMethod() {
         super.doSave();
     }

     @Override
     public void doSave() {
         super.doSave();
     }

 }
```

If I add the `@Transactional` annotation to `Inherited.someMethod`, the interceptor gets called without issue.

However, without the annotation on the inherited class, the interceptor does not get involved in the call to the super class from `Inherited.someMethod()`.

Furthermore, calling `Inherited.doSave()` does not seem to get the interceptor invoked either. I would have expected the annotation on the superclass to be also valid on the subclass. Is this not the expected behaviour?

I am using Apache DeltaSpike for the `@Transactional` annotation and this is being deployed as a war in an ear (technically as a jar in a war in an ear). However, this may not be relevant as trying with a custom interceptor shows the same behaviour.

This is JBoss EAP 6.3.0 Alpha in case its relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected.  Interceptors are only applied if the object is managed.  When you you write it this way with inheritence, it's not applied as it's not part of a call stack that CDI is aware of.  You would need to inject `Base` into your class and call `Base.doSave`

Comment: Thanks. Is this also the case if the subclass overrides the method in the superclass i.e. The someMethod above is renamed to doSave?

Comment: Can you clarify by editing your question or posting a new question?

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me, in EAP.  According to this, we set `Transactional` to `Inherited`: https://github.com/johnament/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/modules/jpa/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/jpa/api/transaction/Transactional.java#L42

Comment: I am not sure what the accepted answer was: "not possible" or "bug in EAP" ... @John: could you update please?

Comment: @JanGalinski the EAP bug is related to the transactional interceptor only.